# How to Return Values From thread Back to main()

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, pthread-join

I am using pthread_create to create a thread that examines the amount of lines in a file, then returns the answer to the main thread.  I have tried using pthread_join, and malloc() but I am new to both and must have used them improperly.  If anyone knows how to pass an integer from a thread back to the main, please help.  My code is below.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *count_lines(void *arg)
{
   FILE *fh= (FILE *) arg;

   int num_lines=0;
   char ch;
   for(ch=getc(fh); ch!=EOF; ch=getc(fh))
      if(ch=='\n')
         num_lines=num_lines+1;
   fclose(fh);
   int* value = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
   *value=10;
   pthread_exit(value);
}

int main()
{

   FILE *fh;
   fh=fopen("data.txt", "r");

   pthread_t my_thread;
   pthread_create(&my_thread, NULL, count_lines, &fh);

   void *retval;
   pthread_join(my_thread, &retval);
   int i = *((int *)retval);
   free(retval);
   printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

I am running an Ubuntu virtual machine and using Visual Studio Code if that is of any help.  When I run the code above I get a "Core Dump (Segmentation Fault)" error.  Again, an help is much appreciated.

Comment: The compiler should dump warnings, don't ignore them.

Comment: `printf` and `getc` are C functions, but you include the C++ header `<iostream>`. You should ock one language, instead of mixing 2. It's sheer coincidence that this even compilers.

Comment: Visual studio code isn't working with pthread so I have to use terminal and terminal throws no warning

Comment: Do you use C or C++? Please do not use both tags when you do not ask about differences, similarities, how to create code to work in both or something like that.

Comment: @MSalters `printf()` and `getc()` are also C++ functions. I am not saying they should be used in C++ but it is valid and well defined to use them when done correctly.

Comment: Yes, but in that case they should be included from `<cstdio>`. I just removed the C++ tag and `<iostream>` since it didn't seem at all relevant.

Comment: @MSalters, Re, "printf and getc..." The issue is not that they are implemented in C or, that they are imported from the C standard library. The issue is that it's unwise to use functions imported from two different libraries to do the same thing. E.g., mixing C standard library file I/O and C++ standard library file I/O in the same program.

Comment: @Alt, Perhaps you are learning something from this exercise, but be aware that it never makes sense for any real program to join a thread immediately after creating the thread without doing any interesting thing in between. The whole point of threads is to allow two different things to happen concurrently, but your `main()` function does not do anything concurrently with the thread that it launches: It just waits for a result.

Answer (score 1):

You are making everything needlessly complicated. Make a struct such as this:

```
typedef struct
{
  FILE* fp;
  int   ret_val;
} count_lines_type;

static count_lines_type cl;
cl.fp = fopen (...);
...
pthread_create(&my_thread, NULL, count_lines, &cl);
```

Fill in `ret_val` before the thread is done.

I made the struct instance `static` just in case the calling thread would go out of scope before the count lines thread is done. If it never does that, `static` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Before you create a thread, check if the file is really opened:

```
fh=fopen("data.txt", "r");
if (fh == NULL) exit(1);
```

Also fh is already a pointer. You **dont need to pass &fh** (pointer to pointer) to thred create (you're expecting FILE* not FILE** in count_lines).
Also check if thread creation succeeded:

```
 if (pthread_create(&my_thread, NULL, count_lines, fh) != 0)
    exit(2);  //error -> contents of my_thread is undefined in this case
```

Also check the retval (dereference only if valid pointer, otherwise segmentation error):

```
if (retval != NULL)
{
   int i = *((int *)retval);
   free(retval);
}
```

Comment: The file is opened, I think something is happening with the malloc() but I don't know what